# firebase_auth/unknown error after app release

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yReFi.jpg)

[firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.j:an internal error has occurred.[json conversion failed! ] failed to parse error for string[   Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1  ...]

web , emulator works fine!!!!
android , web app created
firebase SDK entered
sha1 entered
sha256 entered
INTERNET allowed on andrroidmanifest.xml
google.services.json entered
_minsdkver 21
_targetsdk 29

Comment: log in register in apk on my phone=> firebase_auth/unknown

Comment: tried so many ways , plz help

Comment: please show me your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved : use special v.p..n.s firebase not works with android hardware if you are in iran or banned countries .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).